# How to read SMS data and Transfer it to the Document or CSV file

Tags: javascript, java, android, sms, document

I'm supposed to develop a Mobile Application using SMS data, wanted to use Skip-Gram and Bow Algorithm for the gathered data. The problem is, how to read SMS data and transfer it to the "document file" using Java or a Javascript. Is there any library or something that can gather all SMS data?

I'm sorry I'm new in Programming.

**SMS**

[Sample SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdWQk.png)

**DOCUMENT**

> "hey babe here's your first clue look at the nappa valley wine map
>   what winery is at b10 madonna state good next clue what's my favorite
>   band radiohead open the front door and look on the porch what's
>   waiting for you flowers you won"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need SMS permission for this, android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"

folderName inbox or sent

```
public List<Sms> getAllSms(String folderName) {
        List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
        Sms objSms = new Sms();
        Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/"+folderName);
        ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
        mActivity.startManagingCursor(c);
        int totalSMS = c.getCount();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

                objSms = new Sms();
                objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
                objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
                objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));

                lstSms.add(objSms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        // else {
        // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS in " + folderName);
        // }
        c.close();

        return lstSms;
    }
```

To publish app in play store with SMS permission you have to clearly mention why you need this permission for more info https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-developer-policy-call-log-sms/

Comment: is there any library I need to import?

Comment: No need to use any library.